# google maps event timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get a time stamp from a google maps listener event? I want to have a mousemove event but I need to be able to throttle it. Here is some code of what I am hoping to accomplish. The reason I need a google maps event is for the lat/lng it also returns.

```
var lastMoved = 0;
google.maps.event.addListener(mapObject, "mousemove", function(event){

    if(event.timeStamp - lastMoved > 1000){
        alert("Hello!");
        lastMoved = event.timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `new Date().getTime()`

Here is a very basic example of timed click event for google maps http://jsbin.com/atotiq/1/edit. You can apply the same approach for mousemove event.